# Can't mount drive in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, mount

I am currently getting the message:  *Unable to mount "DATA"  Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 3).Failed to mount '/dev/sdb6': Input/output error*

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 dual booted with Win 7.  The Ubuntu OS is on one of two partitions on one HDD, the other partition being ntfs labelled "DATA".

This message is recently occurring despite the fact that Ubuntu previously read this partition and Win 7 still reads it. I have reinstalled Ubuntu but no change.

I've tried various workarounds gleaned from the forums, but no luck.  Obviously I'm not experienced enough to work it out for myself.  Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just **google your error** `"mount exited with exit code 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 3)"` and found this: http://wmarkito.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/how-to-fix-mftmirr-does-not-match-mft-record-0/

wich recomendds to use ntfsprogs `sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs`.

then on a terminal do

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/partitionName
```

check it out...